# What is a 'slow request'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, client-server, httprequest, httpclient

I see this term mentioned in Rails and other frameworks, and there are even gems to solve for it. How can a client send a 'slow request' (besides his connection being slow and he sending too much data)?

Comment: You already nailed it... a slow request is a normal request slowed down by internet connection and sending too much data. Or processing time takes longer than expected...

Answer (score 0):

`slow request` term is used on the server side when you know that server is taking too long to process a request. And there could be various reasons for slow performance like database query, memory etc.